# How to add a string list to a Dictionary correctly

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I can't add elements correctly to a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` with a `List<string>` like value. Every time I enter a new key with a List as value, the values ​​of the previous keys are overwritten with the last List entered.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> videosBloqueDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<string> videosResult = new List<string>();
string[] bloques = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();

            foreach(var bloque in bloques)
            {
                string[] videos = Directory.GetFiles(path + "\\" + bloque).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
                videosResult.Clear();

                foreach (var video in videos)
                {
                    string[] val = video.Split(' ').Skip(1).ToArray();
                    string result = string.Join(" ", val);
                    videosResult.Add(result); **//list with the new values ​​to enter the dictionary**
                }

                videosBloqueDict.Add(bloque, videosResult);
            }
```

For example:

> string[] bloques = {01:00, 02:00, 03:00} (Keys I will add)

Actual Dictionary:

> - Key = 01:00, Value = {yx, yy, xxx}
> - Key = 02:00, Value = {yx, yy, xxx}
> - Key = 03:00, Value = {yx, yy, xxx}

Expected Dictionary:

> - Key = 01:00, Value = {xxx, yxy}
> - Key = 02:00, Value = {xyy, yyx, yyy, yyx, yy}
> - Key = 03:00, Value = {yx, yy, xxx}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists are reference types, so `videosResult` is a reference to a single list. Every turn of the loop, you clear the same list, and then add another reference to that same list to the dictionary. That's why you end up with identical results for each entry in the dictionary: it's the same list repeated multiple times.

You need to create a new list on each loop, and while you're at it, since you don't actually need the list itself outside of the loop, you should *declare* it in there directly:

```
// don't declare videosResult here

foreach(var bloque in bloques)
{
    string[] videos = ...;

    var videosResult = new List<string>(); // create a new list instead of clearing the original one

    // rest of the method
}
```

By the way, you don't need so many calls to `ToArray()`: if you're going to immediately start enumerating those values, just leave them as `IEnumerable<T>` and, well, enumerate them. `ToArray` creates unnecessary copies here, since it should only be used when you really *need* an array.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, now it works perfect. I'll take a look at leaving it as IEnumerable instead of calling toArray.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> videosBloqueDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

string[] bloques = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();

            foreach(var bloque in bloques)
            {
                List<string> videosResult = new List<string>();
                string[] videos = Directory.GetFiles(path + "\\" + bloque).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();

                foreach (var video in videos)
                {
                    string[] val = video.Split(' ').Skip(1).ToArray();
                    string result = string.Join(" ", val);
                    videosResult.Add(result); **//list with the new values ​​to enter the dictionary**
                }

                videosBloqueDict.Add(bloque, videosResult);
            }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it fixes the problem, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.